# Best way for page break with book tabs table

Tags: page-breaking, booktabs

What is the best practice for the displaying of booktab tables with page break? I could not find any solution but when I use the code from my example, I get alawys confused by a missing separation before the page break. Maybe, the coloring of each second row in a table would improve the looking but then again the last row on a page mustn't be the white row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{17cm}

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}llll@{}}\toprule
\# & A & B & C\\
\midrule
\endhead
1 & A & B & C \\
2 & A & B & C \\
A & A & B & C \\
3 & A & B & C \\
4 & A & B & C \\
5 & A & B & C\\
6 & A & B & C\\
7 & A & B & C \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "missing separation" do you mean you want a rule at the bottom? (you can use \endfoot` to put something at the bottom of each page.)

Comment: something that ends the table in my example before the page number 1. I just you understood it and I will try that

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of `longtable` is that it can go over more than one pages.  To get a footer saying table is continued in the first part of the table and an header table continues for the following parts of the table you have to write some more commands into your `longtable`.  See the following MWE and look to the included comments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{16cm}

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}llll@{}}%
\caption{Longtable \label{tab:longtab1}}\\ \toprule % table caption, ref label
\# & A & B & C\\   % head first part of table
\midrule           % line head body
\endfirsthead      % Definition of 1. table header
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{continue table}\\
\# & A & B & C\\   % head following parts of table
\midrule           % line head body 
\endhead      % Definition of all following headers
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{table continues}\\ % footer 1. (and more) part(s) of table
\midrule
\endfoot      % foots of the table without the last one
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot  % the last(!!) foot of the table
1 & A & B & C \\
2 & A & B & C \\
2a & A & B & C \\
3 & A & B & C \\
4 & A & B & C \\
5 & A & B & C\\
6 & A & B & C\\
7 & A & B & C \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

with the result 1. part of table:

[image]